# How do I fix chromosome-specific Michigan Imputation Server error (Imputation on chromosome 14 failed. Imputation was stopped)

Tags: vcf, imputation

I am imputing human genome samples, all hg19, using the Michigan Imputation Server. The input of the data is one VCF per autosome, which each VCF containing a few dozen samples.

The samples within the VCF are from highly heterogenous sources (various genotype arrays, from multiple labs). I have cleaned and standardized the data (removed indels, multiallelic sites, duplicates, and non-standard genotypes). I merged the samples into a single file for each chromosome. The VCF may not be left-aligned.

It passes all QC with no issues, and then fails and gives no error message beyond "unfortunately, your job failed" and "Imputation on chromosome 14 failed. Imputation was stopped."

As a test, I imputed chromosome 1, chromosome 13, and chromosome 14  by themselves. Chromosome 1 and 13 worked perfectly, but chromosome 14 failed imputation. I have no idea why chromosome 14 would be special or different. Also, imputing chromosomes 1-13 failed on chromosome 9, so it appears only certain chromosomes are causing issues.

Does anyone have ideas as to why this might be occurring, or how to fix this issue?

I dislike using hg19. I am using that because that is the build that some of the genome data I received is on. Labs are still using hg19 in the present day, for some reason. However, I have used hg19 successfully on the Michigan Imputation Server before, and it supports both hg19 and hg38, so I don't think build is the issue. I have a different batch of hg38 data that I will run through the server later.

Here is a comparison between the QC statistics:

| Chromosome: | 13 (success) | 14 (failure) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SNPs | 75,675 | 69,049 |
| Chunks | 6 | 6 |
| Datatype | unphased | unphased |
| Build | hg19 | hg19 |
| Reference Panel | apps@1000g-phase-3-v5 (hg19) | apps@1000g-phase-3-v5 (hg19) |
| Alternative allele frequency | > 0.5 sites: 14,015 | > 0.5 sites: 11,776 |
| Reference Overlap | 99.18% | 99.25% |
| Match | 44,261 | 39,947 |
| Allele switch | 0 | 0 |
| Strand flip | 0 | 0 |
| Strand flip and allele switch | 0 | 0 |
| A/T, C/G genotypes | 0 | 0 |
| Filter flag set | 367 | 342 |
| Invalid alleles | 20,567 | 18,022 |
| Multiallelic sites | 12 | 16 |
| Duplicated sites | 0 | 0 |
| NonSNP sites | 0 | 0 |
| Monomorphic sites | 9,963 | 10,302 |
| Allele mismatch | 138 | 116 |
| SNPs call rate < 90% | 43,096 | 38,760 |
| Excluded sites in total | 74,143 | 67,558 |
| Remaining sites in total | 1,165 | 1,187 |
| Typed only sites | 367 | 304 |
| Execution status | successful | successful |

Per the Michigan Imputation Server documentation, I've checked my input VCF files with CheckVCF.

Here are the results on the chromosome VCF file that failed:

```
---------------     REPORT     ---------------
Total [ 69095 ] lines processed
Examine [ 49 ] VCF header lines, [ 69046 ] variant sites, [ 21 ] samples
[ 0 ] duplicated sites
[ 0 ] NonSNP site are outputted to [ test.check.nonSnp ]
[ 0 ] Inconsistent reference sites are outputted to [ test.check.ref ]
[ 0 ] Variant sites with invalid genotypes are outputted to [ test.check.geno ]
[ 11947 ] Alternative allele frequency > 0.5 sites are outputted to [ test.check.af ]
[ 34408 ] Monomorphic sites are outputted to [ test.check.mono ]
---------------     ACTION ITEM     ---------------
* No error found by checkVCF.py, thank you for cleanning VCF file.
```

Here are the results on the chromosome VCF file that succeeded:

```
---------------     REPORT     ---------------
Total [ 75718 ] lines processed
Examine [ 49 ] VCF header lines, [ 75669 ] variant sites, [ 21 ] samples
[ 0 ] duplicated sites
[ 1 ] NonSNP site are outputted to [ test.check.nonSnp ]
[ 0 ] Inconsistent reference sites are outputted to [ test.check.ref ]
[ 0 ] Variant sites with invalid genotypes are outputted to [ test.check.geno ]
[ 14059 ] Alternative allele frequency > 0.5 sites are outputted to [ test.check.af ]
[ 37553 ] Monomorphic sites are outputted to [ test.check.mono ]
---------------     ACTION ITEM     ---------------
* No error found by checkVCF.py, thank you for cleanning VCF file.
```

Comment: I would suggest chunking chromosome 14 and performing each chunk sequentially. I don't do eukaryotes full stop, but thats how I'd do it. I think there's a getter / setter absent in an algorithm.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you think chunking might work? And I'm not sure how to handle that with imputation. Perhaps it impute "beyond" each chunk somehow, and then combining again would be difficult?

Comment: Generic divide and conquer (how coders think), breaking the problem into smaller pieces ('chunks'). If its a data issue, one 'chunk' would fail. If it was RAM (unlikely) chunking would get around the problem. ... Again I don't do eukaryotes, esp. the human genome. Someone must have done this already via bcftools, vcftools etc ... the bits of the human genome I've done I noted I could code it just as easily as existing tools.

Comment: Okay, got it. Good idea; chunking would help narrow down where the problem is in the data.

Comment: Yep thats it exactly and then compare 'chunks' which work, which don't.

Comment: If you're chunking, make sure to create overlapping chunks. The resulting haplotypes can then be merged together by their overlapping regions using standard tools. I wrote one a while back (https://bitbucket.org/wkretzsch/hapfuse/src/master/), but bcftools should do the trick as well.

Comment: @BigMistake I've deleted your cross-post on Biostars because you have this bad habit of asking every question on both places.

Comment: @RamRS is that against the rules? I looked and couldn't find guidelines, and also waited until the next day, to post there as there are no answers here. If you have a page that details that / other rules, let me know so I don't break any of them in the future.

Comment: It's not in the rules, it's common etiquette. Also, you were asked to not do that once, so if you had a problem with that, you should have addressed it then. There is a meta post on this BTW: https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/about-posting-queries-in-stack-bioinformatics

Comment: @BigMistake Stackexchange will not act against cross-posts because that requires a change in the  Code of Conduct (CoC) which is determined centrally. Biostars belongs only to Biostars and has autonomy to do what it wants. However, here we will put a cross-post link into the post. Thats fair for all concerned. I agree cross-posting isn't ettiequte but it is common.

Comment: @M__ Thanks. I was having a bit of trouble understanding why cross-posting wasn't liked. I think I mostly get it now. I will make sure to add urls. Though personally, adding content to both sites seems like it would make it more searchable and be an improvement, as long as the answer is copied to both sites with credit to the original author of the answer, so maybe I don't quite understand the ettiequte.

Comment: @BigMistake I'm afraid you can't copy and paste answers between sites. The  answer belongs to the author via SE's copyright, so in theory only the author could do that - but no-one else. I don't know how Biostars copyright works however. E.g. if the author posts here first and then copy-pastes to Biostars - thats fine. However, if Biostars own the copyright not the author that author could  not copy-paste their answer from Biostars to here.

Comment: Good point. Then, saying "answer here" with a link to the original site at least in a comment might be better.

Comment: @winni2k When I try chunking, 100% of the chunks work despite the overall file not working. However, I'm not sure if creating overlapping chunks is necessary since I'm using the Michigan Imputation Server--it looks like they combine everything into chromosomes no matter what.